# How to change the SelectionMode of Listbox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

The question is easy, I want to change the SelectionMode of Listbox in my program, but I found it's hard to work it out.

Comment: How are you wanting to change it, in the Xaml or the Code behind, and what problems are  you experiencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ListBox.SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) uses the [`System.Windows.Controls.SelectionMode Enumeration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you would use it like this.

```
//Your three options
listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Single;
listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Extended;
listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;
```

**Xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Height="100"  SelectionMode="Extended"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <ListBox Height="100"  SelectionMode="Multiple"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="147,10,0,0" Name="listBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <ListBox Height="100"  SelectionMode="Single"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="284,10,0,0" Name="listBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
</Grid>
```

If you want something other than this you will need to be more specific on what your **Exact** problem is.